# Is there any intuition behind the statement $E[X_\tau \mid \mathcal{F}_\sigma]=X_\sigma$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, stopping-times

Is there any intuition behind the statement $E[X_\tau \mid \mathcal{F}_\sigma]=X_\sigma$ a.s.
I mean I know that the interpretation of the conditional expectation and how to visualize it somehow but I kind of lose track when I see stopped processes as they are way abstract for me to make any real sense of it. I mean I can use the definitions and prove a few things but then I would really like to understand the relevance of these stopping theorems.

P.S: In my course on continuous time finance we did a lot of stopping theorems and their proofs which I think I understood but then I have no intuition
Sorry if this question is not very precise but I have been struggling with this for quite some time and I felt compelled to ask

Comment: $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are stopping times?  Without additional assumptions, there is no reason to expect $E[X_{\tau} \vert \mathcal{F}_{\sigma}]=X_{\sigma}$.  Perhaps: stochastic process $(X_t)$ is a martingale with respect to stochastic basis $(\mathcal F_t)$ and $\tau \ge \sigma$.

Comment: If you use \mid rather than \vert or |, then you get proper spacing when things are on both sides of \mid and you don't get that spacing when things are on only one side of \mid.  I changed it to \mid. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you I will keep it in mind .

Comment: @GEdgar I am sorry , I should have been more precise. What I mean is given the assumptions on the stopping times and the continuity of the process( and Closedness etc) and applying one of the stopping theorems we get the result and I was hoping for some intuition on the result

Answer (score -1):

It is relatively intuitive. It says that your information of the past up to now doesn't help you to predict the future. Your expectation is neither higher is smaller of current's value.
You mentioned studying finance. Those traders who follow trend for example , think it is not martingale and they follow the trend because they think the expected price in the future is not equal of today's value.

Comment: I wanted to know how to interpret the conditional expectation with the stopped processes and the stopping time sigma algebra as a filtration

Comment: I'm sorry your question is vague. You need to be more specific .